# Parameter count mismatch with Windows Form ShowDialog delegate

Tags: .net, delegates, c++-cli, invoke

So I am simply trying to show a form from a different thread from the GUI thread. For the life of me I can't see to set up my arguments correctly for the invoke which gives me the error message from the catch:

“parameter count mismatch”

Any ideas how I should properly setup the arguments to pass in?

```
#pragma once
#include "ErrorSystemStop.h"
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;

delegate DialogResult ShowErrorWindow(System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^ parentForm );

void ThrowErrorWindow(System::String^ strErrorMessage, int iNumberOfSegments, System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^ parentForm)
{
//Only throw if we need too.
if(!bErrorPause)
{
    MainDisplay::ErrorSystemStop ^ stopMe = gcnew MainDisplay::ErrorSystemStop(strErrorMessage, iNumberOfSegments);
    ShowErrorWindow ^ disp = gcnew ShowErrorWindow(( System::Windows::Forms::Form ^)stopMe, &MainDisplay::ErrorSystemStop::ShowDialog);
    stopMe->TopMost = true;
    try
    {
        cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^> ^ Args = gcnew cli::array<System::Windows::Forms::IWin32Window ^>(1);
        Args[0] = parentForm;
        stopMe->Invoke(disp,( System::Windows::Forms::Form ^)stopMe, gcnew array<System::Object ^>{Args});
    }
    catch(Exception ^e)
    {
        e->Message;
    }
}
} //end ThrowErrorWindow
```

I've also tried:

```
array<Object^> ^ Args = {parentForm};
stopMe->Invoke(disp,(System::Windows::Forms::Form ^)stopMe, Args);
```

Thank you,

Alikar

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out I was passing in three parameters, I was just so tired last night I failed to notice.

I've condensed the code down to this:

```
delegate void ShowErrorWindow(ErrorThrowClass ^ form, System::String^ strErrorMessage, int iNumberOfSegments );

void ThrowErrorWindow(System::String^ strErrorMessage, int iNumberOfSegments, System::Windows::Forms::Form ^ parentForm)
{
//Only throw if we need too.
if(!bErrorPause)
{
    ShowErrorWindow ^ disp = gcnew ShowErrorWindow(&ErrorThrowClass::LaunchErrorWindow);
    MthrControl(DataProtect,M_UNLOCK,M_DEFAULT);
    try
    {
        array<Object^> ^ Args = {parentForm, strErrorMessage, iNumberOfSegments};
        parentForm->Invoke(disp, Args);
    }
    catch(Exception ^e)
    {
        e->Message;
    }
    MthrControl(DataProtect,M_LOCK,M_DEFAULT);
}
} //end Throw ErrorWindow
```

The code to launch the other error window is now a static function in the parent GUI object. This allows everything to be launched in one thread.